# Connect to remote Linux server localhost through browser on Windows desktop

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, localhost

I have an application called SpagoBI that is running on a remote server. On the server it can be accessed through http://serverip:8080/SpagoBI. I want to be able to access that url on my windows desktop. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I would do this?

From my research it looks like I need to do port forwarding/SSH tunneling but they are quite alien concepts to me and I can't quite get my head around them. I can ping the server from my local machine also.

Comment: What do you mean by "my windows desktop"? Are you talking about a web browser under Windows?

Comment: Yea sorry. I want to be able to access that link on a browser on my local machine, which is windows.

Comment: ive researched, did you check if you have JRE installed in your windows host?

Comment: Yea I have JRE 1.8

Comment: being honest, we start very bad from the beggining, your post doesnt shows any research, and provide very low information, can you improve the post with more usefull information, still having too many answers for it.

Comment: I can improve my post but in all fairness I'm hardly going to go into saying what jre versions I have installed and things of that detail. Port forwarding and/or SSH tunneling seems to be the way to go but I can't quite get my head around them. This type of stuff is new to me

Answer (score -1):

You have to know remote servers IP address. http://SERVERIP:8080/SpagoBI
If server is running on windows go to command promt and type `ipconfig` if you server is linux in terminal `ifconfig`

Comment: I do know the server's ip, that's what I used to access the application on the server. Using that ip on my local browser doesn't work.

Comment: can you access just  http://SERVERIP:8080/ part? Its probably tomcat running so it show up some info. Does SERVERIP responds to ping ?

Comment: I've tried that too and unfortunately it doesn't work! I can ping the SERVERIP

Comment: Maybe firewall is blocking port 8080 try disable it for a time if you can, if you can't contact admin.

Comment: I don't think that's it either. I was using a VM a few weeks ago and I was able to give the VM an IP and then access that same address on my local browser. I appreciate your input

Comment: well if you run VM on same machine then still you have to forward ports. I have NAT on Linux VM and i forward 8080 to 8080.

Comment: Yea I did stuff with the NAT settings in Virtual Box in order to give the VM an IP but I have no idea how to  do them on the server.